# KPI trackers for a mean-stack website

Tags: web-services, node.js, tracking, mean

I have already created a website using [MEAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MEAN_(software_bundle)).

Now, I would like to add a commercial KPI tracker to track the visits in very details, eg, the number of visits, the number of visitors, the returning visitors, the visitor IP and location, the time they spent.

Additionally, I want to see their monthly/weekly evolution of numbers by graphs.

I used google analytics in some other websites, I feel that there are some metric missing, eg, information about returning visitors, the precise location of visitor. I think I need a service that provides APIs that I can implement in my code, to track more detailed information.